como instalar dash ploty en visual code en un entorno python con una Mac?
Estoy usando una Mac Sonoma 14.5, estoy tratando de crear un dashboard, a la hora de instalar dash-ploty, me aparece que no hay ninguna compatibilidad
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement dash-plotly (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for dash-plotly
estoy un poco perdido ya que soy nuevo en esto!
gracias por la atención

Que yo sepa el paquete "dash-plotly" no existe en PyPi, es simplemente "dash": python -m pip install dash

Enlace a la documentación: https://dash.plotly.com/installation

voy a revisar muchas gracias!
